# Syncing js to cookie to php

Tags: javascript, php

I've made a php-based quiz. If the question is answered correctly, it increases a variable in the localStorage (by a POST request). On the start of the page it turns the current localStorage content into a cookie which is then used in the php to determine the next question.

The problem is: first the number of the last Stored variable gets loaded (as php loads first), so first of all i get the question with the number of the last session i had. Then the storage sets the variable to 1 as it is null. So i get Question #1. It sends the cookie with this variable to the next page so after this question #1 i get question #1 again.
THEN finally it starts incrementing correctly.

How do i go about fixing this behaviour? (I'd even be happy to minimize it)

Comment: Please share your code so we could see what's going on in order to try and help

Comment: I know, my code is in really, really bad shape. but here you go: https://pastebin.com/ZJ0K3zRG